# Activity.this reference on Context

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have an `Activity` with a `ListView` which I've added a listener (`setOnItemClickListener`).
When I'm inside this method from the listener above mentioned:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id )
```

In order to have access to the Activity, I've done this:

```
    MyActivity host = (MyActivity) parent.getContext();
```

From `host` variable, I have access to all `MyActivity` methods and attributes (which aren't static), but I can't access to the `MyActivity.this` reference.

Could someone explain me why? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyActivity.this` would reference the instance of the "outer" MyActivity class when your code ran in an inner class. -- Does it? If so, why would you need the `host` variable?

*Update:* It only just occured to me that you may be missing the fact that everything you would access via `MyActivity.this` from within an *inner* class, you can access via `host` in your specific setup.

*Update:* You seem to have a wrong understanding of the meaning of `this`. Originally, it stands for *this object*, i.e. the class in which your code runs.

With the additional notation `Class.this`, Java enables you to access the instance of the outer class of your code, but only from an inner class.

In the following example, `Class.this` works:

```
class A {
    int a;
    class B {
        void process_a_in_A() {
            A.this.a++;
        }
    }
    // however, this does NOT work b/c
    // static inner classes do not have references t oouter classes
    static class C {
        void process_a_in_A() {
            // error -- class A.C is detached from its outer class A
            A.this.a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in the following example, `Class.this` does not work. The reason is simply that the system cannot know whether there is an Instance of class A and which one of the possibly many instances of class A you want to refer to.

```
class A {
    int a;
}

class B {
    void process_a_in_A() {
        // A here is a class name, not an object reference;
        // so A.this is meaningless in this context
        A.this.a++;
    }
}
```

Once again, please be aware that you asked a question without providing the necessary information to answer it *specifically*, so it can only be answered in general and it looks like you have a wrong understanding about inner classes and the `Class.this` notation.

Comment: Of course, in my code I'm accessing via _host_. My question comes because I don't understand **why I can't access to `MyActivity` attributes via `MyActivity.this`** . Further, when I type in eclipse "host", it shows me a lot of possibilities, but **this** isn't included. Thanks

Comment: What you are saying is correct. But you haven't understood my question (certainly I haven't explained well). I have the host object

Comment: @user1205781 So is your remaining question, why Eclipse does not show `host.this`? If that is your question, then the answer is: `host` and `host.this` would be identical. What would you need it for? It would result in an endless nesting of choices, because then, `host.this.this` would also have to be shown? ;) -- If this is not your question, can you please re-phrase it?

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had in mind that **this** was accessible from an object (It's a silly thing, I know, but I thought that it was legal so I was intrigued) which isn't legal. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, within any class, you can reference to itself via its Name -> Name.this (especially used for inner-classes)

As you already have your object referenced in the variable host, why not just use it then?!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tell you the same as Class Stacker above.